# How to pull out TRUE/FALSE stratum result from R cox regression?

Tags: r, cox-regression

I have the cox model:

```
res <- coxph(Surv(time,status)~drugName*strata(preventative),data=df)
```

time - integer 0 to N
status - integer 0 or 1
drugName - categorical variable e.g., "drugA", "drugB" etc.
preventative - boolean TRUE/FALSE

From:

```
summary(res)
```

I see results for:

```
drugA
drugB
drugC
drugA:strata(preventative)=TRUE
drugB:strata(preventative)=TRUE
drugC:strata(preventative)=TRUE
```

However, I can't seem to get out the results for the strata where preventative=FALSE.

I've been assured by a clinical epidemiologist that this is possible, however, I use R and she uses SAS.

Besides rerunning the calculation and changing the preventative term TRUE/FALSE around, how can I do this in R?

**EDIT #1** As per Julius Vainora's reply.

I've now tried:

```
res <- coxph(Surv(time,status)~drugName*strata(preventative),data=df)
```

and

```
res <- coxph(Surv(time,status)~drugName:strata(preventative),data=df)
```

The respective results are:

[image]

**and (the new suggestion)**

[image]

If the new suggestion will help just clear the values of the categorical variable *preventative*, any idea why the *drugNamecitaloprame* in the first model has a value but NA in the second model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current results already include what you want: `drugA` corresponds to `FALSE` and `drugA + drugA:strata(preventative)=TRUE` corresponds to true. As to get the same results in a more clean way, you may run instead

```
coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ drugName:strata(preventative), data = df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I've added an edit for clarification as I have a follow-up question.

Comment: @AnthonyNash, the baseline hazard function can be seen as a constant term. Then, say, in the first model amitriptyline is missing since amitriptyline+propranolol+citalopram=1 so that they separately cannot be identified (collinearity issue). Similar relations can be shown between other variables in the first and second models. That is, whenever something is missing or not identified, that is due to collinearity induced by the baseline hazard function.